# How to do xslt type transformations in Marklogic or Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, marklogic, nosql

I am looking into a noSQL solution for data connectivity and transformation into other data structures - specifically at marklogic and couchbase.

My question: How can I do transformations like xslt in a json based database?

Comment: MarkLogic 8 stores native JSON as well. But this question doesn't fit SO guidelines, so I suspect it will be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with CouchBase to comment on its capabilities.

MarkLogic allows for simple transformations using XPath or JSONPath via [REST PATCH requests](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PATCH/v1/documents).  I wouldn't call it "like xslt" but it is definitely a way to update specific portions of JSON documents.  Additionally, MarkLogic allows for [server-side transformations written in Javascript](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms#id_77476) if that's more your style.  Transformations and patches are available to users of MarkLogic's REST API, Java API, and Node.JS API.

Comment: Thanks. great answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, MarkLogic support SPARQL which can perform RDF transformation, if that is the data format of choice, and can be serialized in XML or JSON formats.  Unlike Couchbase, RDF triples can either be represented in documents, normally as document metadata, or as a triple store.  Documents can both represent metadata about the document and provide typed relationships to external RDF  based, including linked open data.

Answer (score 0):

Convert JSON into XML using MarkLogic JSON module and use XSLT language:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace json = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json" at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";
declare variable $j := '{"content": {"name": "Joe Parent","children": [{"name": "Bob Child"}, {"name": "Sue Child"}, {"name": "Guy Child"}]}}';
let $doc := json:transform-from-json($j),
$params := map:map(),
$_put := map:put($params,"childName","Bob Child")
return xdmp:xslt-invoke("/templates.xsl",$doc,$params)
```

where "/templates.xsl" was inserted into **module** database:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $xslt:= <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="json" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:param name="childName"/>
<xsl:template match="json:content">
&quot;ParentName&quot;:<xsl:if test='$childName = json:children/json:json/json:name/text()'>&quot;<xsl:value-of select="json:name/text()"/>&quot;</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
return xdmp:document-insert("/templates.xsl",$xslt)
```